# Application of differential calculus

Tags: calculus, differential

I am having some trouble with this question in my grade 11 math textbook. We are learning applications in differential calculus. It is a question that can be solved many different ways but our teacher is asking us to do it using calculus. I am stuck and do not know what to do here

The question is:

The total cost of producing $x$ blankets per day is $1/4 (x^2) + 8x+20$ dollars, and for this production level each blanket may be sold for $(23 - 1/2 (x))$ dollars. How many blankets should be produced per day to maximise the total profit?

If you could explain in detail how you arrived at the answer (which is 10 blankets) using differential calculus it would be great.

P.S I know that to find profit you need to subtract revenue with cost, but I do not know how to get there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each blanket may be sold for $(23−\frac{1}{2}x)$ dollars, the profit for $x$ produced blankets is:
$$
p(x)=x\left(23−\frac{1}{2}x \right)-\left(\frac{1}{4}x^2+8x-20\right)=-\frac{3}{4}x^2+15x-20
$$
Now derive:

$$
p'(x)=-\frac{3}{2}x+15
$$

and find the maximum for $p'(x)=0 \Rightarrow x=10$.

Comment: But why did you have an x at the beginning of the first equation?

Comment: because in a day are produced $x$ blankets, each sold for $(23-x/2)$.

Answer (score 0):

The profit when producing (and selling) $x$ blankets a day is

$$x \left( 23 - \frac{1}{2} x \right) 
    - \left( \frac{1}{4} x^2 + 8 x + 20 \right)$$

Now you are all set up...

Comment: you have a mistake!  I suppose...:)

Comment: @EmilioNovati I hope to have fixed it...